# Custom stack for md-dialogs rarely causing scope to break

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dialog, angular-material

**PREMISE**

One of the limitations I saw with angular-material when switching from Bootstrap was that there was no inherent mechanism for having multiple dialogs in a single workflow (at least, not from the perspective of the documentation). To remedy this, I created my own stack and what I considered to be a reasonbly abstracted mechanism for using it effectively. This file is reproduced below.

**PROBLEM**

Mostly, it works as you'd expect. However, very rarely (and seemingly without consistency) closing a dialog also breaks the associated scope if the dialog was originally created with an existing scope. Sometimes, this manifests as subsequent dialogs failing to open, or if they do open failing to populate the bindings nested within. In other cases, it causes every angular element on the parent page to fail. Standard links work fine, but any ng-click events, etc no longer function. I have no idea why this is happening. I was hoping a fresh set of eyes would help me find whatever stupid mistake I made that is causing this.

**USAGE**

The stack can be used in two ways: *push* or *replace*. If you push a new dialog to the stack, any current dialog is hidden and stored in a such a way that its context is preserved. This basically means that all of the parameters used to generate the modal in the first place are stored in an object and pushed onto the stack, which is an array stored locally in the DialogStack service. After this, the render function generates a new modal using the highest element on the stack. If you choose to replace, the process is actually the same, except the stack is cleared completely before the new dialog is added.

The actual dialog parameters are stored in a global object, DIALOGS. There are default parameters used in all dialogs (DIALOGS.DEFAULTS), and then each dialog created for the system has its own set of properties, include a templateUrl and a brief description. Occasionally they will also have overrides of the standard properties. When the dialog is rendered, the object associated with the current dialog is mixed with the DIALOGS.DEFAULTS object using Lodash in such a way that the custom properties take priority. Of particular note is the preserveScope property, which in DIALOGS.DEFAULTS is set to true. I had hoped to expand how this flag is used, but in the interest of stability it is mostly left alone. The issues that I'm seeing result from dialogs with preserveScope untouched (set to true).

Note that there's also a utility function to use the built-in confirmation dialog, which generates its parameters using the basic constructor instead of the DIALOGS object.

**CODE**

*Plunker*: https://embed.plnkr.co/MZ74mV0FMGirJd1LYm64/

*DialogStack:*

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name dialogsuite.service:DialogStack
 * @description
 * # DialogStack
 * Handles dialog management under angular-material
 */
angular.module('dialogsuite')
  .factory('DialogStack',
    ['$mdDialog', '$q', '$rootScope',
     'Util',
     'DIALOGS',
    function ($mdDialog, $q, $rootScope,
              Util,
              DIALOGS) {

    var stack;
    var processing;
    // var debugCount = 0;

    /**
     * Removes all dialogs from the stack
     **/
    function clear (hideAll)
    {
      if (!!hideAll)
      {
        stack = [];

        renderDialog ();
      }
      else
      {
        if (!!stack && stack.length === 1)
        {
          processing = false;
        }

        $mdDialog.hide ();
      }
    }

    /**
     * Closes the visible dialog
     **/
    function close ()
    {
      if (!stack || !stack.length) { return; }

      $mdDialog.hide ();
    }

    /**
     * Shows a confirm dialog and calls the appropriate callback
     **/
    function confirm (message, confirmCallback, cancelCallback)
    {
      if (!stack)
      {
        stack = [];
      }
      else if (!!stack.length)
      {
        processing = true;
      }

      var params = $mdDialog.confirm ()
                    //.title('Confirm Action')
                    .textContent (message)
                    .ariaLabel ('dialog')
                    .ok ('CONFIRM')
                    .cancel ('CANCEL')
                    .theme ('default')
                    ._options;

      params.onRemoving = function () { pop (); };

      stack.push (params);

      $rootScope.$evalAsync (function ()
      {
        $mdDialog.show (params).then (confirmCallback, cancelCallback);
      });
    }

    /**
     * Removes the dialogue at the top of the stack. If there are any dialogs
     * remaining, opens the next one down
     **/
    function pop (force)
    {
      if ((!!stack && !!stack.length && !processing) ||
          (!!stack && !!stack.length && force === true))
      {
        var removed = stack.pop ();

        $rootScope.$broadcast ('llDialogClosed', removed);

        renderDialog ();
      }

      processing = false;
    }

    /**
     * Adds a dialog to the stack and opens it immediately
     **/
    function push (dialog, scope, locals)
    {
      if (!dialog)
      {
        throw 'Exception: No dialog provided';
      }

      if (!stack)
      {
        stack = [];
      }

      processing = true;

      if (!!scope)
      {
        dialog.scope = scope;
      }

      //Note: Locals get injected into the dialog's controller
      if (!!locals)
      {
        dialog.locals = locals;
      }

      stack.push (dialog);

      renderDialog ();
    }

    /**
     * Closes any dialog that may currently be open, then shows the dialog at
     * this top of the stack
     **/
    function renderDialog ()
    {
      /*
      locals     {object=}:   An object containing key/value pairs. The keys will be used as names of values to inject into the controller. For example, `locals: {three: 3}` would inject three into the controller, with the value 3. If bindToController is true, they will be copied to the controller instead.
      onShowing  {function=}: Callback function used to announce the show() action is starting.
      onComplete {function=}: Callback function used to announce when the show() action is finished.
      onRemoving {function=}: Callback function used to announce the close/hide() action is starting. This allows developers to run custom animations in parallel the close animations.
      resolve    {object=}:   Similar to locals, except it takes promises as values, and the dialog will not open until all of the promises resolve.
      */

      if (!stack || !stack.length)
      {
        $mdDialog.hide ();
        processing = false;
        return;
      }

      var params = _.assign (DIALOGS.DEFAULTS, stack[stack.length - 1]);

      params.onRemoving = function () { pop (); };

      $rootScope.$evalAsync (function ()
      {
        //When a modal becomes visible, any previous modals are automatically
        //hidden. By doing this manually we can clear the processing flag without
        //destroying the rest of the stack, since onRemoving resolves before the
        //promise does
        $mdDialog.hide ()
        .then (function ()
        {
          processing = false;
          $mdDialog.show (params);
        });
      });
    }

    /**
     * Replaces the dialog stack with the given dialog
     **/
    function replace (dialog, scope, locals)
    {
      stack = [];

      push (dialog, scope, locals);
    }

    /* ********************************************************************** */

    //Service public-facing functions
    var DialogStack = {
      clear: clear,
      close: close,
      confirm: confirm,
      pop: pop,
      push: push,
      replace: replace
    };

    return DialogStack;
  }]);
```

*DIALOGS*

```
app.value ('DIALOGS',
  {
    'DEFAULTS':
    {
      autoWrap: false,
      clickOutsideToClose: true,
      disableParentScroll: true,
      escapeToClose: true,
      focusOnOpen: true,
      fullscreen: true,
      hasBackdrop: true,
      parent: $('body'),
      preserveScope: true
    },
    'MODALROOT':
    {
      desc: 'multi-purpose container, usually for displaying messages',
      fullscreen: false,
      name: 'root',
      templateUrl: 'modal-root.html'
    }
  })
```